# Exporting and importing catalog, products data using phpmyadmin in Magento

Tags: magento, phpmyadmin

I have a broken site and i want to clean install magento but i want to keep using my old catalog and products. Is it possible to extract and populate catalog from old db to new. please let me know how and which folder to copy.
Edit : I am not a expert in php mvc or magento so i wont dive into code as i have some frontcontroller error saying about the router reach 100 etc

Answer (score 0):

Magento offers a "repair"-Tool for the Database, if your site is broken, tell us WHAT is broken? Is it the DB or did you screw up with code? None the less, its not easy backing up the catalog due to the EAV Model. If you have access to the backend try exporting your catalog as csv and reimport it again.

But to be honest: If your db is broken try to fix it, if your code is broken, try to find out what is broken and then come back again

Comment: I don't have access to backend otherwise i would have done that. I have a error which says Front controller reached 100 router match iterations,Trace:
#0 .../app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(183): Mage::throwException('Front controlle...')
#1 .../app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(304): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#2 .../app/Mage.php(596): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#3 .../index.php(80): Mage::run('', 'store')
#4 {main}
I tried running a fresh install and use old db but i have same error,not sure why.happened to when server got upgraded..

Comment: Ah, seems like your url-rewrites are messed up. Try to fix it by removing every route with numbers at their end. E.g: sony1/* it should look like sony/* The table you're looking for is core_url_rewrite

Comment: which col should i be looking it as i dont see anything like u mention

Comment: try id_path or target_path i cant tell you which one it is exactly, but i can tell you that your problem is mostly caused by doubled routes. Try a reindex of the urls via console. Navigate to your shell folder and type "php indexer.php --reindexall"

Comment: shell, you mean command line for mysql? sorry never used shell as i typed in mysql cmd line it said you have mysql error. so i am presuming that it isn't for there.sorry for this, but can u guide me. I am using MAMP.

Comment: i dont know about macs but try this: cd /path/to/magento [Enter] cd shell [Enter] php indexer.php --reindexall [Enter] See if that works

Comment: says permission denied. @Soundz :/

Comment: then grant yourself permission on unix system do chmod 755 -R /path/to/magento/shell

Comment: I got this message [link](http://screencast.com/t/vhvojTAN1iVp) i checked table after it but values are still there.is the result right?

Comment: [link](http://screencast.com/t/UHzv6DavZmw) this is output i get after running the indexer.for some reason i think its not what should be output.

Comment: well... thats the reason i dont own a mac, they suck beeing servers. Try setting up a virtual machine (i advise debian) and try to run your store there. If its still broken we look at it again

Comment: don't have a windows based or other linux based.However i do have cpanel and it got ssh but never used it and nothing work when i click on it ssh terminal like pop up or java applet. i am stuck :/

Comment: will truncate that table will help?